# get the output of yolov8 tflite model

Tags: yolov8, tflite

this is the code

```
final output = {
      0: [List<num>.filled(10, 0)],
      1: [List<List<num>>.filled(10, List<num>.filled(10, 0))],
      2: [0.0],
      3: [List<num>.filled(10, 0)],
};
```

the output.values.toList(); return [1,10]

can someone help me to modify the code for obtaining this output [1,84,8400]